# Codeigniter Mysql:Too many connections

Tags: codeigniter-3

I am getting following error:

Message:  mysqli::real_connect(): (08004/1040): Too many connections

Here is the code of my DB config

```
$db['default'] = array( 'dsn'   => '',
 'hostname' => 'localhost', 
 'username' => 'root', 
 'password' => '', 
 'database' => 'gatha_data', 
 // 'database' => 'storegrunt-dev', 
 'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
 'dbprefix' => '', 
 'pconnect' => FALSE, 
 'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
 'cache_on' => FALSE, 
 'cachedir' => '', 
 'char_set' => 'utf8',
 'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci', 
 'swap_pre' => '', 
 'encrypt' => FALSE, 
 'compress' => FALSE, 
 'stricton' => FALSE, 
 'failover' => array(),
 'save_queries' => TRUE );
```

Please reply as early as possible

Comment: Hi, Welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: update your question and show the code of database configuration

Comment: Hi,Thanx for reply.

Comment: Following is database configuration:

Comment: $db['default'] = array(
 'dsn' => '',
 'hostname' => 'localhost',
 'username' => 'root',
 'password' => '', 

 'database' => 'gatha_data',
//        'database' => 'storegrunt-dev',  

 'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
 'dbprefix' => '',
 'pconnect' => FALSE,
 'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
 'cache_on' => FALSE,
 'cachedir' => '',
 'char_set' => 'utf8',
 'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
 'swap_pre' => '',
 'encrypt' => FALSE,
 'compress' => FALSE,
 'stricton' => FALSE,
 'failover' => array(),
 'save_queries' => TRUE
);

Answer (score 0):

You can increase this value in main config file (e.g., /etc/my.cnf) using this syntax:

```
[mysqld]
set-variable=max_connections=250
```

and also you can change php.ini file

```
; Allow or prevent persistent links.
mysql.allow_persistent=Off
```

Or You can set

```
'pconnect' => TRUE,
```

Comment: As per my knowledge 'pconnect' should be FALSE

Comment: mysql.allow_persistent=Off  Here we are closing persistent connection so by making pconnect True will open connection